# differences in NN optimization algorithm between Matlab and Scikit-Learn

Tags: neural-network, scikit-learn, python-3.x, matlab

I'm trying to build a neural network to estimate the responses of a **nonlinear system**. My database contains 1000 load cases (inputs) and maximum responses (outputs) from numeric simulations.

I'm using Python Scikit-Learn. I've run a gridsearch on the hyperparameters but the NN does not provide reliable results. I ended up with **two hidden layers**, 20 and 30 neurons, **relu** for activation function.

Not anything like what I've seen on articles and tried myself with Matlab: good results with **one hidden layer**, 20 neurons, **logistic** for activation function.

I wonder what could be so different between Matlab and Scikit-Learn to yield such a difference in the net architecture and its performance. Can it be the performance of optimization algorithms available in each?

Comment: If you compare apples to apples, i.e., same architecture, activation function, learning rate, etc., do you get similar results?

Comment: @rickhg12hs, not similar at all.